# Как получить тип обобщения в объекте?

Tags: c#, массивы, generics

У меня есть массив с типом `EventHandler<EventBase>[]`. В массиве есть объекты класса `EventHandler<T>`, где `T` - может быть любым классом, который наследуется от `EventBase`. Есть условие, что тип обобщения в массиве не повторяется

Мне нужно написать функцию, которая достает элемент из массива, тип обобщения которого задан типом обобщения самой функции. Например, мне надо найти объект с типом `EventHandler<DamageEvent>` (`DamageEvent` наследуется от `EventBase`). Для этого мне надо вот так вызвать эту функцию `GetHandler<DamageEvent>()`

Я бы это сделал и сам, но вот только не знаю, как узнать тип обобщения у объекта

Comment: А что вам мешает написать проверку `array[i].GetType() == typeof(EventHandler<T>) `?

Comment: @PavelMayorov Эхех, что-то я не додумался. В любом случае, узнал про GetGenericArguments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тип аргумента обобщенного класса можно узнать с помощью метода [`GetGenericArguments` класса `Type`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.type.getgenericarguments%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

```
List<int> x = new List<int>();
var a = x.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];
Console.WriteLine(a.Name);
```

Он возвращает массив аргументов обобщения, а, так как, у вас всего один аргумент - просто возьмите из этого массива элемент с индексом 0.

Таким образом, ваш метод будет выглядеть как-то так:

```
EventHandler<EventBase>[] eventHandlers = new EventHandler<EventBase>[...];

EventHandler<EventBase> GetHandler<T>()
{
    return eventHandlers.Single(eh => eh.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0] == typeof(T));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

На самом деле ваша задача не имеет никакого отношения к Generics или проверкой Generic Type Arguments.

Вам нужно в массиве объектов найти экземпляры определенного типа. С этим хорошо справляется стандартный `Enumerable.OfType()`:

```
EventHandler<T> GetHandler<T>()
{
    return eventHandlers.OfType<EventHandler<T>>().Single();
}
```

Никакие динамики или явный reflection не нужны.

---

И, на всякий случай - убедитесь, что в коллекции действительно лежат экземпляры нужного типа. Не уверен, что у вас происходит в коде, но со стандартным `System.EventHandler<T>` вы просто не сможете положить в коллекцию `EventHandler<EventBase>[]` экземпляр `EventHandler<DamageEvent>`, т.к. EventHandler от `EventHandler<EventBase>` не унаследован.

Т.е. код ниже не скопмилируется:

```
EventHandler<EventBase>[] eventHandlers = new EventHandler<EventBase>[2];

eventHandlers[0] = SomeHandler1;
eventHandlers[1] = new EventHandler<DamageEvent>(SomeHandler2);
```

и вам придется хранить хэндлеры как `object[]`

Answer (score 2):

Если скорость не важна, то можно выполнить фокус с `dynamic`.

Например, есть функция

```
public void ProcEvent<T>(T[] events)
{
    foreach(var e in events)
        ProcEvent((dynamic)e);
}
```

И 3 перегрузки вызываемой функции, своя для каждого типа

```
public void ProcEvent(object @event)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Object called");
}

public void ProcEvent(EventHandler<DamageEvent> @event)
{
    Console.WriteLine("DamageEvent called");
}

public void ProcEvent(EventHandler<EventBase> @event)
{
    Console.WriteLine("EventBase called");
}
```

Работу можно проверить так:

```
var events = new object[] { 
    new EventHandler<EventBase>((s, e) => {}) ,
    new EventHandler<EventArgs>((s, e) => {}) ,
    new EventHandler<DamageEvent>((s, e) => {}) ,
};

ProcEvent(events);
```

Вывод ожидаемо такой

```
EventBase called
Object called
DamageEvent called
```

Плюсы: код короче

Минусы: код медленный, ибо рефлексия. Код чуточку запутанный, ибо рефлексия :)

Comment: Код не на много короче. Да и он не оч подходит к моей архитектуре приложения

Comment: @Minebot решать конечно вам, я просто за полноту вариантов. Вам не подойдет, мож кому другому подойдет.